# Why do I need Visual C++ 2008 redistributable?

Tags: windows, c++

I have `Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 redistributable x64` installed on my computer it takes up 4GB of space from which I could greatly benefit from gaining. I don't understand why I need the Visual C++ on my computer.

Is it safe to uninstall this program?

Is there a complete list of programs somewhere which actually use the Visual C++? Are there any alternatives that are smaller that I could install, instead.

I really need the disk space and this is the largest program on my computer

Comment: How do you know it takes up 4GB of space?

Comment: Microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable x64 does not take up 4GB of space, I don't care what Add/Remove Programs says it takes, its not a 4GB package.  While you can uninstall the program its very likely you have an application or more then likely a video card that requires it.  If you use Steam then it will just be reinstalled.

Comment: @Paul thats what add/remove programs says. haha

Comment: Dont know why it has -2 votes when 2500 people are wondering the same thing as me. Man people like to vote stuff down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable is a set of DLLs that are used by some other software installed on your computer. I really doubt it takes 4GB as it should really take about several (under 10) MB. If you uninstall it there is a chance that one of your installed programs will stop running.